# TC7 (20939) : upgrade : mercurial : http auth : Test Connection Succeeds... but build checks fail (http auth)

Tags: mercurial, teamcity

Have been using EAP 7 for a couple of months, this is the 2nd upgrade.

Upgraded to build 20939 today and now get errors when builds are trying to check mercurial for changes (VCS problem: FOO           Edit this VCS root>>). If I edit the VCS Root and click Test Connection it succeeds. How do I go about debugging this issue?

Have tried re-saving the vcs root. I deleted and recreated the vcs root on one project and get the same result.

The recent entries in the teamcity-vcs log don't have domain\user:password, should they?

I now have both the teamcity and buildagent services running under my AD account. I don't remember what account the teamcity service was using before the upgrade (is that logged somewhere?).

If the vcs root is configured with an 'https://' and has user/password why don't I see the credentials in the log message (see above post)?

My user directory contains mercurial.ini / ssl cert (and was working pre-upgrade).

TeamCity hosted on Windows2k8, mercurial repo, using Active Directory credentials for authentication.
teamcity service is running as Local System
buildagent running as AD account (for builds that deploy to other machines)

newest errors:

[2012-01-11 17:12:39,578]   WARN [cutor 4 {id=29}] -      jetbrains.buildServer.VCS - Error while loading changes for root mercurial: https://mycompany.com/myproject {instance id=29, parent id=8}, cause: 'cmd /c hg pull https://mycompany.com/MyProject' command failed.
stderr: abort: http authorization required

older errors:
[2012-01-10 16:38:02,791]   INFO [TeamCity Agent ] -      jetbrains.buildServer.VCS - Patch applied for agent=computer {id=1, host=127.0.0.1:9090}, buildType=Project :: MVC3 {id=bt12}, root=mercurial: https://mycompany/myproject {instance id=12, parent id=1}, version=3775:7fc0ae5029e6

[2012-01-11 10:30:36,277]   INFO [_Server_StartUp] -      jetbrains.buildServer.VCS - Server-wide hg path is not set, will use path from the VCS root settings

Answer (score -1):

The problem persisted after a complete uninstall/re-install.

In the VCS Root definition... I left the user/password fields blank and encoded the user:password into the 'Pull changes from' string (just like you'd do on the command-line.

https://domain\user:password@hg.mycompany.com/Repo

To sorta clean up the plaintext password I created a project level property 'MyPassword' (type password) and used it in the connection string like this:

https://domain\user:%MyPassword%@hg.mycompany.com/Repo

Still not great but I'm up and running and the password is not viewable by causal users.